# Selenium Webdriver take screenshots

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I want to use the Selenium Webdriver to take screenshots of paragraphs of a post on reddit given a reddit URL. I got it working with the following code:

```
while True:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/p[{}]".format(counter))
            element.screenshot("paragraph{}.png".format(counter))
            counter = counter + 1
        except Exception:
            break
```

This works almost all of the time. However, I noticed that sometimes if the post is too long, the screenshot cuts off. When Selenium webdriver opens the web browser and goes to the URL, the paragraph where it cuts off on screen is where the screenshot will cut off and take only half or a quarter of the paragraph for example. For example, if a post has 10 such paragraphs and paragraph 5 cuts off on the screen, the screenshots for paragraphs 1-4 and 6-10 will be perfect. However, paragraph 5 will be cut off. I know I could maximize the screen before I take the screenshots but I dont think this is a great solution because some posts might be even longer so it wont help in those cases.

I was wondering if there are ways to prevent this to get the screenshot of the full paragraph. I was thinking about scrolling down the page but I am not sure how to detect when the paragraph will cut off to do so.

Comment: IE was great for this kind of thing since it would take full page shots.  However, since IE's pretty much dead and gone, you might just try executing a javascript which scrolls the element into view: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Yea that’s what I was thinking too but how would I know which element is at the bottom of the page

Comment: Doesn't much matter just send the command to scroll whatever element you are targeting into view first.  (Hopefully it fits...)  Maybe add a small sleep afterwards.

Comment: got it, very insightful info! thanks!